# Packaging wearable apps

Tags: android, android-studio, packaging, wear-os, watch-face-api

I'm in the last stage of developing a watchface service for the android wear devices. The problem is the following:
Every time i try to sign my app, two files are being generated: wear-release.apk and mobile-release.apk , there is no other apk. Shouldnt the apk name be my Packagename of the projectdirectory? 
-Because i tried opening both files with my compatible Smartphone (with a weardevice attached), which always ends instantly in a phrasing  error.

Thinngs i have noticed:

- There is no content in the mobile version package in Android Studio
- The permissions are only mentioned in the mobile Manifest (also tried with the permissions being on both manifests)
- it's a normal werable watchface with no config activity
- Ihe mobile-release apk is way lager than the wear-apk although i have nearly nothing placed in the mobile part. (--> good ,maybe wear-apk is already in the mobile-apk)?
- I tried to install the apks from the SD card and the phone memory
- i have install apks from unknown sources turned on.

Thanks for your help & time -Botti560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking "Generate Signed APK" Make sure module "mobile" is selected from the drop down. The generated APK containing both wear and mobile modules will be named "mobile-release.apk". Also settings.gradle should have `include ':mobile', ':wear'` present and also build.gradle (Module: mobile) should have

```
dependencies {
    wearApp project(':wear')
}
```

**EDIT more content / clarification added below**

OK with this edit hopefully I can help you solve your issues!

First off, make sure you are running the latest stable version of Android Studio. As of today's date the latest version is Android Studio 1.1.0
I previously had some issues generating a signed APK on an earlier version. Second make sure you have have the latest SDK files including the latest API (API 22).

Once you have this setup, if generating a singed APK for your app still does not work. I would try making a new android project. Set Minimum SDK for phone to API 18 (4.3 Jelly Bean, the lowest API level compatible with Android Wear). And set the Minimum Wear SDK to API 20 (Android 4.4 KitKat Wear).

Then try to generate a signed APK of this new project without making any changes to it. THIS SHOULD WORK! If you are still having issues, then something is seriously fouled up and I would just reinstall Android studio from scratch.

If this new project does indeed work, then take note of any differences between the manifest and gradle files of this working project and your other, non working one. Any discrepancies you find might very well be your issue.

Finally three files: build.gradle (Project: anAppImade), build.gradle (Moduble: mobile), and build.gradle (Module: wear) should look something like this (respectively)

**build.gradle (Project: anAppImade)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (Moduble: mobile)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ppltalkin.anappimade"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

**build.gradle (Module: wear)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ppltalkin.anappimade"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.87'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, but i did it exactly as you both mentioned before. The werd thing is, that both files are generated , when i only select mobile to install. But that may be not important or normal.
But i get the phrasing errror all the time :/

Comment: these are my mobile dependencies:                                        dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile "com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.+"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+'

}

Comment: I edited my original post and hopefully it will help you you!

Comment: THANKS!! These are some great tips, i'm just writing finals right now, so i can't test it right away. -greetings from Germany Botti560 .D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use android studio:

Your mobile build.gradle file should have the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   wearApp project(':wear')
}
```

Go to Build > Generate signed apk.  In the first window, select mobile as your module.

Now when the build is complete, the wear module will automatically be embedded into the mobile module.  The mobile apk is the one you distribute.  Wear can be used for testing.

view [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) for more detailed instructions.

Comment: Apk not embeded, I followed your instructions